# UITableViewCell with aspect fitting images and autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know this has been asked 200 times, but i just don't understand.
So, the goal is as simple as can be. A tablecell with an image and 2 labels below, the images have **different aspect ratios**.
I actually got it to work, but i just don't understand why something that should be extremely common, is that difficult/hacky.
I set up my tablecell autolayout. Connecting all the edges, setting the image to aspect fit, set an expected height on my tableview, dont set any height constraints.

I think where the problem comes in is that the tablecell uses the intrinsic contentsize of its subviews to calculate its height? And for some reason, the intrinsic height of the "aspect fitted" image, is the height of the original image?
So if you have quadratic images, one is 200x200 and one is 1000x1000, they actually scale to the same size, just one has 5 times as much useless whitespace top/bottom. Why would this be the default behaviour of an option that resizes your imageview?

There are solutions which work for me, for not async loaded images, which include setting a width/height constraint based on the aspect ratio.
I can still kinda do it by fetching like 5 images ahead of time, then set those in my model objects and then do the refreshing constraint thing via a class or tablecell addition.

I guess my questions are, is there an easy/intuitive solution? Do i at least somewhat grasp whats causing this problem?

Comment: Why not just show your constraints?

Comment: You can replicate the behaviour with just an empty imageView in a cell pinned to all 4 edges.

Comment: 4 edges of what?

Comment: top = contentview.top, bot = contentview.bot, leading = contentview.leading, trailing = contentview.trailing